# $scope variable doesnt integrate with express api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, single-page-application

The static part of the app seems to load ok. I recently added a service which uses the express as a simple api, but when I try to set the #scope from my module's controller it seems as if it hasn't even loaded. Puzzled why this is happening because it claims to find and load everything correctly based on server output... Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Here is my project: https://github.com/Abott1222/Simple-Mean-App

GET / 304 4.637 ms - -

GET /js/angular.min.js 304 1.523 ms - -

GET /js/angular-route.min.js 304 1.627 ms - -

GET /style.css 304 0.376 ms - -

GET /app/app.js 304 0.391 ms - -

GET /app/controllers/todoListController.js 304 0.730 ms - -

GET /app/controllers/todoController.js 304 0.717 ms - -

GET /app/services/todoProvider.js 304 0.666 ms - -

GET /app/partials/todo_list.html 304 0.269 ms - -

Answer (score 0):

I forgot that to work with node you need to make the api calls async. The change is in static/app/controllers/*

$scope.todoList = todoProvider.getAllTodos();

to

```
$scope.todoList = todoProvider.getAllTodos(function (err, todos) {
    $scope.finished_loading = true;
    if (err) {
        $scope.page_load_error = err.message;
        } else {
            $scope.todoList = todos;
        }                
    });
```

Hope that might help somebody... Sorry my question may have been too vague :)